# php-cgi.exe quits after exactly 500 hits

Tags: php, windows, nginx

For the life of me, I can't figure this out.

This is my development machine setup:

Windows 7 Home Premium 64 bit,
Webserver: NGINX 1.3.6 c:\users\user_name\devel\nginx
PHP: 5.4.7 c:\users\user_name\devel\nginx\php5

Everything works fine except that after exactly 500 hits, my php-cgi.exe quits unexpectedly.  No error logs, no events, nothing.  It just dies after 500 hits...EVERY SINGLE TIME.  I haven't found a single source of information online to help me on this. All the configuration seems valid and good.  This is happening on two different machines (my development desktop and my notebook).  I've tried different nginx.conf and php.ini files...still the same.

I just need to get a better idea on how to go about debugging this.  Any suggestions?

Comment: How are you launching php-cgi? According to http://wiki.nginx.org/FcgiExample#Spawning_a_FastCGI_Process, you should probably be using "php -b 127.0.0.1:<port>" and letting the PHP process manage the php-cgi.exe processes. The limited number of requests is by design, to mitigate the risk of resource leaks (database connections, memory, etc.) in a script.

Comment: It's launched exactly like that.  (well...on windows it's php-cgi.exe -b 127.0.0.1:9000)  I swear this is the strangest thing I've ever seen...

Comment: It looks like there are tools to help with this, such as supervisord and php-fpm. See http://www.mikepreston.org/2011/11/23/fastcgi-php-and-supervisord/ for notes on supervisord configuration. I don't think you're alone in trying to address this (see also http://serverfault.com/questions/275340/how-to-restart-php-cgi-automatically-with-spawn-fcgi).

Comment: Wooo.  Thanks for finding that serverfault thread.  I'll follow that and see.  Thank you!

Comment: Sure, sorry I couldn't provide a direct answer. If you do find a solution, please post it as an answer to your question here as well.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I finally figured it out.  Maybe it was simple enough that I couldn't find the solution.

Adding:

```
SET PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS=0
```

to the command file that launches the php-cgi.exe fixed it.  I guess it defaults (when not set) to 500 hits before FCGI is killed.

Obviously, there are good reasons for this and as GargantuChet has suggested, settings things up correctly and letting the instances of PHP managed and auto-spawn is a better way to go...but for people who want a quick windows development environment, this can solve some problems.

Comment: .you saved me brother.

Comment: You have to be careful using this... the purpose of the restart is to get a fresh start on memory leaks, etc. By disabling that, you stand the potential of crashing your server.

Answer (score 7):

The selected answer works, but doesn't allow the CGI server to shut down every so often (after 500 hits in the OPs case).

Like the OP and others mentioned, this shutdown is necessary in a production environment to curtail memory leaks.

In Windows, another solution is to create a batch file that looks like this:

```
:start
    php-cgi -b 127.0.0.1:9000
    goto start
```

This will allow the shutdown that was designed to occur, and will almost immediately start php-cgi again.

Answer (score 3):

If you add

```
SET PHP_FCGI_CHILDREN=1
```

to the command file that launches the php-cgi.exe, it fixed it.

You can add more children if you want, it depends of your need.

Answer (score 1):

unvisible EXE file that will LOOP-RUN php-cgi.exe with passing it own command-line params,
can be easily compiled in, for example, ms-VCpp6 ([phpCgiExeLoop.exe](http://jalija.com/jalija/wintools/phpCgiExeLoop.exe) ~28kb):

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <Shellapi.h>
#include "stdio.h"

int APIENTRY WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                     LPSTR     lpCmdLine,      int       nCmdShow)
{   while (1)
    {   SHELLEXECUTEINFO shExInfo = {0};
        shExInfo.cbSize = sizeof(shExInfo);
        shExInfo.fMask = SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS;   shExInfo.hwnd = 0;
        shExInfo.lpVerb = "open";            // Operation to perform
        shExInfo.lpFile = "php-cgi.exe";     // Application to start    
        shExInfo.lpParameters = lpCmdLine;   // Additional parameters
        shExInfo.lpDirectory = 0;            shExInfo.nShow = SW_HIDE;
        shExInfo.hInstApp = 0;  

        if (ShellExecuteEx(&shExInfo))
        {   WaitForSingleObject(shExInfo.hProcess, INFINITE);
            CloseHandle(shExInfo.hProcess);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

and running "phpCgiExeLoop -b 127.0.0.1:9000" instead of "php-cgi.exe -b 127.0.0.1:9000"
...to win-support php creators intention (avoiding possible memory-leaks).

Comment: That's great could you make it a github/gist repo