# Php can't connect to mysql after application running for a while

Tags: php, mysql, objective-c

I have an IOS application which will call a php file on apche2 server and send the query to mysql server (all of them are running locally on my mac OS X). If I submit the data as soon as I open the app, than everything goes fine. I can insert a new log to mysql server. However if I remain my app open for 15-60 min (randomly), my app is still working fine, however mysql will not respond to the php anymore.

Here is part of my objective C code for my app (I don't think there is any problem here)

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://%@/database.php", httpPath]];
NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

NSDictionary *params = @{@"jwt": user.jwt, @"mysqlCommand" : mysqlCommand};
[urlRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
NSError *error;

[urlRequest setHTTPBody:[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:params options:kNilOptions error:&error]];
```

Here is part of php code that execute the query

```
$conn=new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=something_db',$reader->db_username,$reader->db_password,array(
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE=>PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
));
$stmt=$conn->prepare($sqlStr);
$stmt->execute($params);
```

I have notice from my apache error log for php server that **the php file do have been called** since something do goes wrong like this everytime when that database.php have been called (will trying to solve this later)

> [Fri Feb 17 11:13:31.349827 2017] [:error] [pid 21764] [client
>   172.16.4.186:52869] PHP Stack trace: [Fri Feb 17 11:13:31.349856 2017] [:error] [pid 21764] [client 172.16.4.186:52869] PHP   1. {main}()
>   /Library/WebServer/Documents/mobile/database.php:0

But inside mysql general log, **no connection are being build at that time period**.
Where If I run the program immediately after it is open, something like this would show up.

> Timestamp, Thread, Command Type, Detail
>   2017-02-17 10:23:10.183493, 237, Query, INSERT INTO log (user_id, category, action, app) VALUES('abc','Login', 'Logged into cafeteria', 'CAFE')

I haven't had a systematic studying on php before, therefore I am not familiar with any of it's settings at all so I think it will be safe for you to assume that I am just using defaulting settings for my php server on mac OS X.

I am thinking right now if it is due to session problem, or something related to GC system on php server. Anyone have any clue on what is going wrong with my php server so it is not sending the query where it suppose to do?

Comment: Is that code that's creating the connection being executed every time?  You may want to just open a single connection and reuse it; if it's creating new ones for each query you will eventually hit server connection limit (particularly if they're not being properly disposed of)

Comment: Yes. Actually the whole database.php file will be called each time. But it will be killed every time when the sql response. Could that be a problem?

Answer (score 0):

(Since i can't comment in with rep below 50, i'll write my guess in answer.)

If you are using defaultly configured php cgi and webserver forwarding requests to the the php-cgi, it most likely **dies after 500 requests** (to prevent RAM overflowing etc...) - You will need some form of **FPM**, to keep your PHP-CGI alive. (For me on WIN, batch job with infinite loop till externally killed worked well... Right after PHP-CGI died, the batch job continued and started it again.)

Also this should be worth checking:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/13020563/7581087

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will try to se if it work